# Struts2 Deployement on Oracle weblogic gives issue

Tags: java, struts2, weblogic12c

I have updated the struts2 version from 2.5.13 to 2.5.14.1 but now this gives me an issue while deploying on oracle weblogic server. It says.
(In console)

```
Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "731246539495" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null"
```

and in the error log I am getting

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "oracle.eclipse.tools.common.services".
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not able to deploy the project.

Comment: You should provide details to clarify your problem. Without details and clear problem description that is reproducible itself is impossible to answer.

Comment: There was an existing project build in struts. I had to update the struts version in maven dependencies and I updated the version from 2.5.13 to 2.5.14.1.

The project just runs fine on struts version 2.5.13 but gives Null Pointer Exception in weblogic.ModuleEception. 
This exception just by changing the struts version

The Oracle weblogic version that I used is 12.1.3

Comment: You can't update the version of Struts in the maven config file because you don't know how it could affect the behaviour of the application server used to run your project. Different app servers use different configuration internals that have incompatible configuration in your application. You should check the server log as suggested by your app server to figure out the problem then update this question to understand error. If you feel that is not enough to reproduce the problem them provide the source code, traces of the code that cause the error. Missing relative information doesn't help oth